# Getting LLVM 6.0.0 lld-link to work with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, llvm, codeblocks

I'm trying to get LLVM/CLang 6.0.0 (on Windows x64) to work on Code::Blocks 17.2
The project I'm workign with is called Spectrum_Tester, and is a basic Windows project with a WinMain (and no wxWidgets).

I've got clang/clang++ compiling into .obj files, but lld-link.exe spits out a bunch of errors as follows:

> -------------- Build: Release32--Win in Spectrum_Tester (compiler: LLVM Clang Compiler--Win)---------------
>
> lld-link.exe /LIBPATH:"E:\Compilers\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib" /LIBPATH:"E:\Compilers\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"E:\Compilers\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib\IA64" /OUT:Release\Spectrum_Tester.exe "obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj" "obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj" "obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\ston.obj" "obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\UnInCh.obj" obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\main.obj obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\SpectrumTesterFrontImport.obj obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj  /ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup /ERRORLIMIT:0 -s  gdi32.lib user32.lib kernel32.lib
>
> lld-link.exe: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -s
>
> lld-link.exe: error: : undefined symbol: _WinMainCRTStartup
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__free
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__malloc
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp____std_terminate
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__strlen
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj: undefined symbol: ??3@YAXPAX@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj: undefined symbol: ___CxxFrameHandler3
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CIString.obj: undefined symbol: ??_7type_info@@6B@
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__free
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__malloc
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp____std_terminate
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__strlen
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj: undefined symbol: ??3@YAXPAX@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj: undefined symbol: ___CxxFrameHandler3
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Strings\CSString.obj: undefined symbol: ??_7type_info@@6B@
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\UnInCh.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__malloc
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\UnInCh.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__free
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\UnInCh.obj: undefined symbol: ??3@YAXPAX@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\UnInCh.obj: undefined symbol: __imp____std_terminate
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\UnInCh.obj: undefined symbol: ___CxxFrameHandler3
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Custom Libraries\Utils\UnInCh.obj: undefined symbol: ??_7type_info@@6B@
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: _atexit
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__time
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: ??3@YAXPAX@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__fopen
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: ??2@YAPAXI@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__fclose
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__feof
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__fgetc
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__free
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp____std_terminate
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__malloc
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: _memcpy
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __tls_index
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __tls_array
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __Init_thread_epoch
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __Init_thread_header
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __Init_thread_footer
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __Init_thread_abort
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__sprintf
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: ___CxxFrameHandler3
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: ??_7type_info@@6B@
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\BackEnd.obj: undefined symbol: __fltused
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj: undefined symbol: ??_U@YAPAXI@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj: undefined symbol: __imp__free
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj: undefined symbol: __imp____std_terminate
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj: undefined symbol: ??3@YAXPAX@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj: undefined symbol: ??_V@YAXPAX@Z
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj: undefined symbol: ___CxxFrameHandler3
>
> lld-link.exe: error: obj\Release\Spectrum_Tester\TesterLists.obj: undefined symbol: ??_7type_info@@6B@
>
> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
>
> 50 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

How do I resolve these?

lld-link.exe is supposed to be almost fully compatible with MS Visual Studio's link.exe, FWIW.

Also, I've tried the command line with /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS and with /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS in place of /ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup and gotten the same result.